# How to show input field, if "other" is selected as option in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get this field to stay hidden and only show when a user selects "other" in the drop down, but also hide the field if the user clicked it by accident and then changes the option to a value that is not "other". The following code is made from a survey that I'm trying to edit with some CSS and JS, so I do not have access to the actual code to change things.

HTML:

```
<select name="1684_51635_4_146338" id="1684_51635_4_146338" onchange="choiceSelected('1684_51635_4_146338', this.selectedIndex);" class="howHear">
    <option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="Family or Friend">Family or Friend</option>
    <option value="Service provider referral">Service provider referral</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
<tr valign="top" class="old-school">
    <td width="5%" class="req" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="wrapable" for="1684_51635_5_146441">
            <span class="aural-only" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">Question - Not Required -</span>
            <div class="explicitWrap">Other:</div>
        </label>
        &nbsp;
        <br>
        <span class="NetscapeFix"><input type="text" name="1684_51635_5_146441" id="1684_51635_5_146441" value="" size="30" maxlength="40" class="otherHear"></span>
        <br>
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've added classes `.howHear` and `.otherHear` to them using JS, and then attempted this to hide the field and show it based on option:

```
//if other selected in howHear drop down, show .otherHear input field
   $('#1684_51635_4_146338').on('change',function(){
        if( $('#1684_51635_4_146338').val()==="other"){
        $("#1684_51635_5_146441").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#1684_51635_5_146441").hide()
        }
    });
```

However, the problem is the "other:" input field is always showing doesn't matter if an option is selected or not. I tried looking at other solutions on SOF but couldn't get them to work for this either. Note that I am using other drop downs on the survey that also have this.selectedIndex as part of its onchange function if that makes a difference.

All suggestions are really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: In this line `if( $(#1684_51635_4_146338).val()==="other"){` you need to place quotes around the selector.

Comment: @JamesDouglas I don't think its just the typographical error. They need to keep the input hidden to begin with, so that it is hidden initially and shows up when they select "other".

Comment: @Barmar I accidentally deleted the quotes in the question I posted as I was posting the latest thing I tried when I copied and pasted it in. My real issue was that display none wasn't added to the other field, thank you Nisarg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there are two minor issues with your code:

1. The input is not hidden to begin with. So it remains visible until someone selects an option in the drop down.
2. The selector syntax is invalid in the `on-change` event of the drop-down input.

```js
//if other selected in howHear drop down, show .otherHear input field
$('#1684_51635_4_146338').on('change', function() {
  if ($("#1684_51635_4_146338").val() === "other") {
    $("#1684_51635_5_146441").show()
  } else {
    $("#1684_51635_5_146441").hide()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="1684_51635_4_146338" id="1684_51635_4_146338" onchange="choiceSelected('1684_51635_4_146338', this.selectedIndex);" class="howHear">
    <option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="Family or Friend">Family or Friend</option>
    <option value="Service provider referral">Service provider referral</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
<tr valign="top" class="old-school">
  <td width="5%" class="req" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
    <label class="wrapable" for="1684_51635_5_146441">
            <span class="aural-only" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">Question - Not Required -</span>
            <div class="explicitWrap">Other:</div>
        </label> &nbsp;
    <br>
    <span class="NetscapeFix"><input type="text" name="1684_51635_5_146441" id="1684_51635_5_146441" value="" size="30" maxlength="40" class="otherHear" style="display:none;"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix! I thought that by using .hide(), I wouldn't need to use display none.